# Custom Sublime Snippets - HTML Style Formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext, erb, sublimetext3

Forgive the vague title, I'm having a hard time figuring out the correct phrase for what I am trying to do.

I have a number of custom snippets I have written to support writing ERB for Ruby on Rails. For this example, I am trying to use an if tag that can be on a single line:

```
<% if something %>Content Here<% end %>
```

or multiple lines with indented content:

```
<% if something %>
  Content Here
<% end %>
```

I am able to get the first (single line) format working fine with the following snippet:

```
<![CDATA[<% if $1 %>${2:$SELECTION}<% end %>$0]]>
```

The problem is that if I type in the trigger, hit tab, type in the conditional for $1, hit tab, then hit return, Sublime does exactly what I type and puts the following:

```
<% if something %>
[cursor]<% end %>
```

Is there a way in the snippet to instead treat the if and end tags like HTML tags:

```
<% if something %>
  [cursor]
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define a new snippet with a new tabTrigger.  It will look something like:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<% if $1 %>
    ${2:$SELECTION}
<% end %>$0]]>
</content>
```

Comment: I considered a separate snippet, but I was hoping to find a way to do it seamlessly with the existing snippet so that 1) changes to the snippet don't require modifying multiple files and 2) I don't have to think through which snippet I want when my mind is working in HTML mode and expects to be able to type the tag code I want and hit return.